# Crop image using php

Tags: php, image, crop

I want to crop an image. Is it possible to do like this. And if yes, how would the `crop()` function look like?

`$imgURL` is always a `.jpg` image.

```
$image = file_get_contents($imgURL);
$maxWidth = 100;
$height = 68;

$image = crop($image, $maxWidth, $height);

file_put_contents("media/imgname.jpg", $image);

function crop($image, $maxWidth, $height){
    ...how do I crop the image?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the GD library installed, taked a look at [the functions available to you](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php). If you want more explanation and an example, take a look at [this blog](http://haugland.ca/entries/general/cropping-with-gd).

Also, there's plenty of [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gd+crop+php) to help you along.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [gd library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) that's usually part of most PHP installs.

Typically, you'd:

1. import the image using one of the imagecreatefromTYPE functions
2. use imagecreate($width,$height) to make a blank buffer image
3. use imagecopy() to transfer the portion you want to the buffer
4. use one of the imageTYPE functions to write the buffer out to a file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use timthumb for croping , using timtgumb you can resize image on fly....

check this http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-resize-images-on-the-fly

here is the result http://joedesigns.com/resizing2/example.php

Answer (score 0):

Another option you may be able to use is Image Magick if it GD is not installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Find below code for image crop using GD library:

```
<?php
function createThumb($upfile, $dstfile, $max_width, $max_height){

   $size = getimagesize($upfile);

   $width = $size[0];

   $height = $size[1];



   $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;

   $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;

   if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height)) {

           $tn_width = $width;

           $tn_height = $height;

   } elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height) {

           $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);

           $tn_width = $max_width;

   } else {

           $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);

           $tn_height = $max_height;

   }



   if($size['mime'] == "image/jpeg"){

           $src = ImageCreateFromJpeg($upfile);

           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);

           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);

           imageinterlace( $dst, true);

           ImageJpeg($dst, $dstfile, 100);

   } else if ($size['mime'] == "image/png"){

           $src = ImageCreateFrompng($upfile);

           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);

           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);

           Imagepng($dst, $dstfile);

   } else {

           $src = ImageCreateFromGif($upfile);

           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);

           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);

           imagegif($dst, $dstfile);

   }

}

//usage

if(isset($_FILES['upload_Image']['name']) && $_FILES['upload_Image']['name']!=='') {
    $ext = substr($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'], strpos($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'],'.'), strlen($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'])-1); 

    $imgNormal = time().$ext;

    $normalDestination = "Photos/Orignal/" . $imgNormal;

    $httpRootLarge = "Photos/Large/" . $imgNormal;

    $httpRootSmall = "Photos/Small/" . $imgNormal;

    $httpRootThumb = "Photos/Thumb/" . $imgNormal;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_Image']['tmp_name'], $normalDestination);



    createThumb($normalDestination,$httpRootLarge,680,604); #For 604x604 Image  

    createThumb($normalDestination,$httpRootSmall,500,300); #For 500x300 Image  

    createThumb($normalDestination,$httpRootThumb,130,100); #For 130x100 Image

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just try doing JCROP plugin from Jquery**

One of the best plugin for cropping images

[deepliquid.com----download JCROP](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)

```
 function cropfun(){         
            $('#previews').Jcrop({ 
                aspectRatio: 3,
                minSize:[300,100] ,
                boxWidth: 450, boxHeight: 400,
                bgFade:true,
                bgOpacity: .5,
                setSelect: [ 60, 70, 600, 330 ],
                onSelect: updateCoords
            });

}

 function updateCoords(c)
        {
            $('#x').val(c.x);
            $('#y').val(c.y);
            $('#w').val(c.w);
            $('#h').val(c.h);
        };

        function checkCoords()
        {

            if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
            alert('Select where you want to Crop.');
            return false;
        };
```

> In the body part

```
     <img  src="uploads/<?php  echo $image; ?>" id="previews" name="previews"  onclick="cropfun();"   />
     <input type="file" name="image22" id="image22" style="visibility:hidd"     >
    <input type="hidden" id="hh" name="hh" value="" />
     <input type="hidden" id="hhh" name="hhh" value="<?php  echo $image; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: He asked for a php not a JavaScript and especially not for a jQuery solution.