# How can I resize and crop an image with PHP?

Tags: php, image, resize, crop

I am looking for some sort of function that will resize an image to 100x100, 200x200 etc but keep the aspect ratio of the uploaded image in tact.

My plan would be to use some sort of cropping, so to crop in the centre of the image after it's height or width reaches 100.

So my logic is a bit like this.

```
if ( $currentHeight > $currentWidth ) {
  //resize width to 100 and crop top and bottom off so it is 100 high
}

elseif ( $currentWidth > $currentHeight ) {
  //resize height to 100 and crop left and right off so it is 100 wide
}
```

In my mind the image would then be 100x100 and it wont look odd!

Does anyone know how I could do this in a tidy function??

Comment: have you searched? google or this site, there are millions of examples

Comment: you could start by looking at the image functions in the php manual, there are heaps of examples in there

Comment: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop image using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372514/crop-image-using-php)

Comment: I have been searching for days, all anyone offers is resizing to width or stretching it out. I don't want to install some dodgy library. I just want a simple function. Can it be done?

Comment: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php the first example in the user contributed notes is pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pure css to crop images to fit specific dimensions using [clip:rect](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html):

```
<style>
/*Size of div that contains the dox*/
.crop{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #474747;
}

.crop img{
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:-25px;
    left:-25px;
    /*       (Top,Right,Bottom,Left) */
    clip:rect(25px 125px 125px 25px);
}    
</style>

<div class="crop">
    <img src="http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif" width="200" title="" alt="" />
<div>
<br/>

<div class="crop">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5" title="" alt="" />
<div>
```

<kbd>**[See In Action](http://jsfiddle.net/4Gvqf/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop central part, then I suppose logic for counting coordinates can be such:

1) Count horisontal coordinats of crop area:

```
$horizontal_center = $current_width/2;
$left = $horizontal_center - $new_width/2;
$right = $horizontal_center + $new_width/2;
```

2) Count vertical coordinates of crop area:

```
$vertical_center = $current_height/2;
$top = $vertical_center - $new_height/2;
$bottom = $vertical_center + $new_height/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer - ive written a imagemagick/php function to do this:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/20927238/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927238/automatically-resize-image-on-the-shorter-side-regardless-of-orientation-in-imag/20928687#20928687)